# Implement a Custom Protocol on Mac for a Cocoa / Qt Application

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, qt

We want to be able to call our application from a browser link (as i.e. MS teams does when you open a link to a teams meeting).

The principle is quite simple and exists since quite a while. Under Windows this consists just of a few registry entries ([How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)).

But anything i tried on the Mac does not work at all.
See i.e. [Mac custom protocol fails on some machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721047/mac-custom-protocol-fails-on-some-machines) or https://web.archive.org/web/20091215155410/http://www.xmldatabases.org/WK/blog/1154_Handling_URL_schemes_in_Cocoa.item (very old...)

I learned that we need:

1. Add CFBundleURLTypes to pInfo.list
2. Add a handler that shall be called by MacOs.

But i dont get it to work at all.
Neither my application gets started after adding the required entries to CFBundleURLTypes, nor is such a Handler in our application ever called.

The Application in Question uses QtWidgets so the code in the application is C++ / Objective-C.

Does anyone have a working sample project or a link to such that does this using Objective-C or even Qt?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a URL to your target (Project > Target > Info > URL Types) [[Example here]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app)

Then, follow [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app) and run your application. From a browser, type in your urlscheme (yourAppName://open) and Safari asks if you want to open the app. This works for a Objective-c application, I don't know what QT is (hopefully not QuickTime)..

Also, I would personally avoid using 10+ year old SO questions as a reference, a lot have happend since :)

Edit: Added a few screenshots to help explain:
[image: Xcode setup]
Run the app to register the URL schema

In Safari, type schema://whatever
[image: In Safari]

User is promted to open the app or not
[image: Dialog in Safari]

Comment: Thanks for your answer - i know theses Docs, but i dont find a working sample, and i am unable to build one.

Comment: In Xcode, select your project file, choose your target and select the 'Info' tab. This list 'Custom macOS Application Target properties' first, and then below, 'URL Types'. Click +, and set an identifier (reverse domain is recommended) [com.example.myApp], and set [myApp] as URL Schemes.
In the AppDelegate, implement -(BOOL) application:(NSApplication*)app continueUserActivity..... Run the app.  In Safari, type [myApp://Open] and it asks to open the app.

Comment: That looks promising. Could you share the full project?

Comment: I created a sample app using Xcode 13 doing just the same, but it just won't work. I uploaded the here: https://www.file2send.eu/de/download/kFf6xo1p8Hl5jsprLKOwkeRgJ8P47ZtOVvx8L2Btt28RjuympAB2lmGi71sCCQSA Can you tell what I m missing?

Comment: I don't know why, but suddenly it seems to work I closed and reload the Xcode project several times etc.

Comment: Ill have to do more investigations on this. It seems to me that xCode does more than advertised - i.e. does more than set CFBundleURLTypes